# superagent dynamic method types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, superagent

I'm using `superagent` and I faced a problem with dynamic method name.
For every method I shoud write:

```
request
  .get(url)

request
  .post(url)
```

Is there any way to pass method name as parameter to superagent like that done in axios

```
 axios({
  method: 'post',
  url,
  data
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use like below check [docs](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#request-basics)

```
request('GET', url).end(callback);// and pass your first param as http verb 'GET','POST', etc...
```

Instead just

```
request.get(url);
```

Or

```
request.post(url);
```